# Instantons in 1+1 dimensional Abelian Higgs model

Tags: field-theory, higgs, topology, instantons

Let's consider the Abelian Higgs model in 1+1 dimensions in Euclidean space-time:
$$L_E=\frac{1}{4e^2}F_{\mu\nu}F_{\mu\nu}+D_\mu\phi^\dagger D_\mu\phi+ \frac{e^2}{4}(|\phi|^2-\zeta)^2$$

where $\zeta>0$ and $D_\mu\phi= (\partial_\mu-iA_\mu)\phi$.

We are looking for finite action field configurations, i.e instantons.
Because in this case $\phi : S^1_{phys}\rightarrow S^1_{gauge}$ and being $\mathbf{\pi}_1(S^1)=Z$,
I expect that for an instanton configuration the action is bounded by its topological number (winding number).
More precisely, the finiteness of the action comes from the following behaviour for large $r$:
$$ 1) \quad\phi(r,\theta)=\sqrt{\zeta}\,g(\theta)$$
$$ 2) \quad A\mu=g\partial_\mu g^{-1}+O(1/r^2)$$
where $g\equiv g(\theta)$ is an element of U(1).

Therefore  I would define the winding number $k$ as the one of pure gauge:
$$w=\frac{i}{4\pi}\int d^2x\epsilon_{\mu\nu}F_{\mu\nu}$$

So I would expect, up to numerical factors, something like: $S\ge \zeta w $, where I have inserted $\zeta$ for dimensional reason.
I am interested in demonstrating that inequality and in solutions  saturating the bound. Any reference on this topic?

Answer (score 1):

Advanced Topics in QFT (Shifman) talks about U(1) anomaly in 1+1, Aspects of Symmetry (Coleman) have topics on Higgs 1+1, and probably something about it in David Tong lectures.